# Bamboo MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, bamboo, msbuild-task

If i provide the options with a quote and without quote still i am getting this MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. error.

The provided options is like this 
msbuild /t:clean /t:build "E:\Atlassian\Home\Bamboo_Home\xml-data\build-dir\AP-BUILD-JOB1\APIFrolic\APIFrolic.sln" /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:TargetPlatformVersion="10.0.10010.0"

Answer (score 0):

> Bamboo MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

The first thing is check the version of your Bamboo, make sure it is the latest version. Starting with the Bamboo 5.5-OD-04, there is bug [BAM-14659](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14659?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab) about this issue:

> MSBuild task keep failing with error "MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified".

If you are already the latest version or update to latest version still have this error, please try to check the settings of Bamboo agent and server. See the workaround to the issue [BAM-15879](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-15879?jql=project%20%3D%20BAM%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Only%20one%20project%20can%20be%20specified%22%20ORDER%20BY%20cf%5B14732%5D%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC) for detail.

> Remote agents.
>
> If you're starting agent manually you simply provide
>   -Dbamboo.plugin.dotnet.msbuild.useResponseFile=true on the command line. If your agent is run as a service then make a change in the
>   $BAMBOO_AGENT_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf configuration file:
>
> ```
> The Bamboo Agent home configuration file
> wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dbamboo.home=/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home
> wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dbamboo.agent.ignoreServerCertName=false
> wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dbamboo.plugin.dotnet.msbuild.useResponseFile=true
> ```
>
> Bamboo server
>
> stop Bamboo add
>   -Dbamboo.plugin.dotnet.msbuild.useResponseFile=true to JVM_REQUIRED_ARGS in $BAMBOO_INSTALL/bin/setenv.sh start Bamboo

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your `/t` parameters:

```
msbuild /t:Clean;Build ...
```